# Go test coverage for test files in separate module

Tags: go, code-coverage, go-testing

I'm running `gotestsum --junitfile-testcase-classname=short --junitfile-testsuite-name=relative \ -- -coverprofile=coverage.out ./serviceName/...`

The structure looks like this:

```
serviceName
  normalModule
     - file.go
     - file_test.go
  testModule
     - file2_test.go
     - file3_test.go
  otherModule 
     - file3.go
  - file2.go
```

How can I generate a test report that will account for all corresponding test files outside of its own module?

Note: I am trying to avoid reorg

Tried above command and expected normalModule, otherModule, and serviceName module to report coverage.

Currently the coverage report only shows a coverage for normalModule and skips the rest:

- serviceName/normalModule (5ms) (coverage: 100.0% of statements)
- ∅  serviceName
- ∅  serviceName/testModule
- ∅  serviceName/testModule

Comment: Why do you have multiple modules in the first place? That's very atypical, and probably a lot more pain than necessary.  Or did you mean separate packages?